# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, date, createdAt, updatedAt, __v})

Tags: reactjs, object, redux, rendering

I get the following error when i try to render an object ({day} see react Component below) coming from the database:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {_id, date, createdAt, updatedAt, __v}). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead.

The object in question looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "5fdf554b88f52f520c93a16e",
  "date": "2020-12-20T10:00:00.133Z",
  "createdAt": "2020-12-20T13:44:43.934Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-12-20T13:44:43.934Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

And the following is my code:

Router:

```
dayRouter.get(
  '/:id',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const day = await Day.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
    if (day) {
      res.send(day);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Booking Not Found.');
    }
  })
);
export default dayRouter;
```

Redux-Action:

```
export const detailsDate = (dayId) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: DATE_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: dayId });
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/day/${dayId}`);
    dispatch({ type: DATE_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: DATE_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Redux-Reducer:

```
export function dateDetailsReducer(
    state = {loading: true}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case DATE_DETAILS_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true };
      case DATE_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, day: action.payload };
      case DATE_DETAILS_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

React Component:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { detailsDate } from '../actions/dateAction';

function BookingConfirmationScreen(props) {  

  const dayId = props.match.params.id;

  const dateDetails = useSelector((state) => state.dateDetails); //from Redux Store
  const { day } = dateDetails;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {

      dispatch(detailsDate(dayId));
    return () => {};
  }, [day,dispatch, dayId]);

  return (
    <h1> Booking {day}</h1>
  )
}

export default BookingConfirmationScreen;
```

What i need to render is actually {day.date} but i get that day is actualli undefined. Which is when i realised that there is an issue with {day}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**day** is undefined because you get that data from the server, so rendering the component is faster than the async call. That is why you have **loading** in reducer, it is set to false when the data is recieved from the server. Destruct the **loading** from  the state like this:

```
 const { day, loading } = dateDetails;
.
.
.
```

then do this in when you are returning:

```
if(loading)
return <div> loading.. </div>
 return (
    <h1> Booking {day.date}</h1>
  )
```

Comment: This is so true. Thanks alot, it worked. I am a beginner and trying to learn, Can i ask you what you meant the this 'you get that data from the server, so rendering the component is faster than the async call' ? I do use async in the router and action. Thanks

Comment: Every time you make a call(request) to the server, you wait for the response, and that function is asynchronous, asynchronous code takes statements outside of the main program flow, allowing the code after the asynchronous call to be executed immediately without waiting, in your case, the component renders without waiting for the data from the server to be received, so that is why at first, the variable day is undefined(haven't received the data yet). I hope you understand. Here is a good documentation about that: https://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/

Comment: This is even better: https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff